# Как правильно писать REST Api с Spring и Java

Tags: java, spring, rest

Я изучаю Java Spring и REST и очень запутался во всех классах и способах решениях одних и тех же проблем. Я посмотрел два онлайн-курса и выполнил туториал спинга (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) и во всех курсах используются разные инструменты. Сначала задам вопрос, потом покажу примеры - что конкретно меня смутило.

**ВОПРОС: как мне выбрать "лучший" и "самый правильный" подход?** Есть ли в них существенная разница (потому что из обучалок я этого не уловил - но они все очень разные) или всё просто зависит от решений команды на месте работы и на результат особо не влияет?

**ПРИМЕРЫ.** Например, код в туториале спринга мне кажется довольно громоздким, но в нём я вижу больше всего логике - их подход с CollectionModel, EntityModel и  ResponseEntity - кажется, это ещё и ближе всего к настоящему REST (к тому, как я его понял из теории).

Методы там выглядели следующим образом (на примере получения всего списка работников предприятия):

```
 @GetMapping("/employees")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Employee>> all() {

        List<EntityModel<Employee>> employees = repository.findAll().stream()
                .map(assembler::toModel)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return CollectionModel.of(employees, linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
    }
```

C другой стороны, здесь не так много классов: только контроллеры, репозитории и классы-сущности из таблиц базы данных.

---

Код из видеокурсов мне показался проще для написания - значит, его писать и читать легче. Там все методы предлагалось делать в таком стиле (всё то же получение списка всех работников предприятия)

```
@GetMapping
public List<Employee> getAll(){
    return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
}
```

И такой метод мне кажется подозрительно примитивным... и не совсем rest-ным. А вот количество классов довольно большое: здесь предлагают кроме классов с @Table, репозиториев и контроллеров использовать также сервисы, перегонять объекты классов с @Table в дополнительные объекты для работы с ними в приложении.... Есть ли смысл такого нагромождения?  В чём смысл тех же @Service, если сервис всего лишь является посредником в обращении к репозиторию и ничего дополнительного не делает?)

Также видел предложение писать вообще не REST, а использовать Модель с атрибутами.

```
@GetMapping("/employees")
public String getAllStaff(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.getAllEmployees());
    return "employees";
}
```

Довольно много гуглил и как раз смотрел все эти курсы с целью развеять все сомнения и ответить на вопросы, но их в итоге стало лишь больше.

Comment: Попробуй другие фреймворки, если не вяжется со спрингом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть один не очень известный факт о REST, это то, что нет единого правильного подхода к REST. На самом деле есть некий спектр [зрелости REST](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

Подробности расписывать не буду, почитайте по ссылке, а еще лучше в книге Rest In Practice.

Так вот, разные подходы в спринг позволяют писать код с разным уровнем зрелости. Использование `CollectionModel` - это самый продвинутый уровень, т.е. если вы реализуете полный [HATEOAS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). С другими способами придется довольно много boilerpate кода написать.

В этом подходе легко и просто делать CRUD, так как вызываются методы репозитория напрямую и получается, что нет той сложности, о которой вы говорите во втором подходе (т.е. нет сервисов и т.д.). Но это простота именно, что для CRUD, более сложную бизнес логику все равно придется выносить в сервисы и, в зависимости от задач, другие уровни.

Второй способ, что вы описали, лучше всего подходит если вам не нужен HATEOAS, а достаточно уровня зрелости 2. Он исторически вырос из "обычных" веб приложений spring, прост и понятен. И в таком подходе не обязательно иметь отдельный слой сущностей в DAO, тут зависит от задач - вполне возможны варианты, когда одни и те же сущности используются от DAO до web.

Третий способ с моделями, это больше годится для MVC приложений, но так же может использоваться и для REST, но с меньшим удобством.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! 
я правильно понял, что сервисы добавили просто как дополнительный слой, чтобы изолировать громоздкую бизнес-логику? и без него можно  обойтись, и это не будет ошибкой? 

третий пример я привёл как показатель того, что можно вообще без реста обойтись и я об этом в курсе) и что результат там, на мой взгляд, получается ничуть не хуже, чем с рестом

возможно мои вопросы глупые, но меня долго запугивали собеседованиями с каверзными вопросами))) пытаюсь разобраться на 100%

Answer (score 1):

Есть задачи и зависящие от этих задач способы решения. Поскольку задачи решаться могут по разному, то говорить о правильных способах в отрыве от этих задач бессмысленно. Поэтому лучший и правильный подход понятие субъективное и зависит от того, с чем вы столкнулись.

Поскольку неизвестно с чем вы столкнетесь, то инструменты делают весьма гибкими. Можно довериться стандартному наименования пути `@GetMapping`. Но вдруг имя будет не подходящим, тогда используете уточнение `@GetMapping("/employees")`. Но по факту это одно и тоже - определение конкретного http пути в системе, главное результат и возможно договоренности внутри команды. Все зависит от того, что вы хотите в итоге получить. Мне к примеру проще с последним подходом вбить в поиск IDE `/emplo` и сразу выйти на метод, чем ковыряться в иерархии с кучей классов.

С другой стороны есть способы решения задач, которые подойдут в >90% случаев и поэтому их можно спокойно использовать. К примеру приложение делится на слои и каждый слой отвечает за свои задачи. Это позволяет избегать путаницы и решает много неочевидных проблем с поддержкой кода и внесением изменений в приложение.

Самая стандартная ситуация, когда у вас есть слой с физической базой данных (Database Layer). Дальше слой описывающие данные в базе (Persistent Layer), который хранит ваши Entity и прочую информацию. Следующий идет слой с бизнес логикой (Business Layer), который описывает логику работу с данными и что с ними можно делать в различных сервисах. Ну и последний слой приложения (Application Layer), который позволяет обращаться к вашим сервисами и работать с данными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь REST как таковой находится в последнем слое приложения, где на картинке HTTPS⇔Request т.к. кроме способа обращения к данным ни за что больше не отвечает. Поэтому последний пример не очень понятен, почему вдруг использование модели (или DTO, когда нужно ограничить или преобразовать выходные данные) становится не REST приложением. Ведь это только внешние правила обращения поверх HTTP, не более.

Оставлю пару ссылок на внешние источники, может они вам помогут:

1. [Organizing Layers Using Hexagonal Architecture, DDD, and Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/hexagonal-architecture-ddd-spring)
2. [Spring Boot Architecture](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-architecture)
3. [Habr: Введение в REST API — RESTful веб-сервисы](https://habr.com/ru/post/483202/)

Comment: Я посчитал, что третий подход не рест, потому что:
1. в курсе он был до реста, в разделе простого mvc
2. потому что там нет нормального http реквеста, просто какая-то модель с атрибутами) 
3. потому что данные не в формате json
Это неправильная логика?) А вообще за ответ и ссылки спасибо

Comment: @egor-n, сам REST является дополнением, поэтому он спокойно строится над тем, что вы изучили ранее путем добавления правил и ограничений. Реквест определяете вы сами, просто работать через модель менее удобно, но допустимо. Есть обязательные пять принципов REST и в них нет ограничения на формат ответа - xml; plain/text; image/* и т.д. допустимы, просто JSON самый удобный и нет особого смысла его менять.

Comment: Пять принципов - клиент и сервер (общаемся запросами), нет сохранения состояния (сервер не хранит данных о клиенте, вся нужная информация в запросах), кеширование (явно указываем кеш это или нет), единый интерфейс (правильно и единообразно задаем пути URL, ответы единообразны и понятны, использует get|post|update|delete и т.д.), слои (цепочка вызовов между клиентом и сервером их не волнует). В основном уделяют внимание единому интерфейсу и ответам.